# How to SUM from another table in SQL in one view?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables
Maintable
and
Secondtable

In the Second Table is a Column Maintable_ID and Price.

I have bulided up a view in Workbench like this:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS 
SELECT Maintable.ID as ID,
       Maintable.Name as Name,
       Maintable.Date as Date,
       Secondtable.Price as Price,
From maintable

LEFT JOIN secondtable
ON Maintable.ID=Secondtable.Maintable_ID
```

I have thought about to make something like:

`SUM(Price) as GPrice FROM Secondtable WHERE Maintable.ID=Secondtable.Maintable_ID`

How Can I find out the total price for all items in the Secondtable where Secondtable.Maintable_ID= Maintable.ID

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
CREATE VIEW test AS 
SELECT Maintable.ID as ID,
       Maintable.Name as Name,
       Maintable.Date as Date,
       sum (Secondtable.Price) as GPrice,
From maintable

LEFT JOIN secondtable
ON Maintable.ID=Secondtable.Maintable_ID
Group by 
      Maintable.ID as ID,
       Maintable.Name as Name,
       Maintable.Date as Date
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider accepting anyone of the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you're just missing a `group by` clause:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS 
SELECT Maintable.ID as ID,
       Maintable.Name as Name,
       Maintable.Date as Date,
       s.Sum_Price as Price,
FROM   maintable m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   Maintable_ID, SUM(Price) AS Sum_Price)
           FROM     secondtable
           GROUP BY Maintable_ID) s
       ON m.ID=s.Maintable_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
  SELECT Secondtable.Maintable_ID ,
  SUM(Secondtable.Price) as GPrice,
  From Secondtable inner join Maintable ON Secondtable.Maintable_ID=Maintable.ID
   GROUP BY Secondtable.Maintable_ID
```